# Best way to handle repeated attribute groups in Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, ruby-on-rails-6.1

What is the best way to handle a scenario in Ruby on Rails 6 where a set of attributes with the same names, types, and purposes is repeated on multiple models throughout the application?

For example, (and note that this really is just an example, not my actual setup), let's say we have a `Person` model with the following database migration:

```rb
def change
  create_table :persons do |t|
    # The usual attributes...
    t.string :first_name
    t.string :last_name
    t.string :email
    # ...

    # Location attributes:
    t.string :country
    t.string :address
    t.string :city
    t.string :zip_code
  end
end
```

Now imagine that we have another completely different model, `Building`, that *also has a location*, like so:

```rb
def change
  create_table :buildings do |t|
    # Some attributes...
    t.string :name
    t.decimal :height
    t.references :type, foreign_key: { to_table: :building_types }
    # ...

    # Location attributes (the exact same ones as for Person):
    t.string :country
    t.string :address
    t.string :city
    t.string :zip_code
  end
end
```

There may also be even more models with a "location".

Now, let's say wherever a location is used throughout the application, an approximate latitude/longitude will be calculated. How then can I write this in such a way so that I am not 1) repeating attributes in the migrations and 2) not repeating related logic (i.e. latitude/longitude calculations)?

#### One Option

One potential solution that I thought of is to create a separate model called `Location` and reference it in `Person` and `Building`. For example:

```rb
# xxx_create_persons.rb

class CreatePersons < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :persons do |t|
      # The usual attributes...
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      # ...

      # Just a single location reference:
      t.references :location
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# xxx_create_buildings.rb

class CreateBuildings < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :buildings do |t|
      # Some attributes...
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :height
      t.references :type, foreign_key: { to_table: :building_types }
      # ...

      # Just a single location reference:
      t.references :location
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# xxx_create_locations.rb

class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :country
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :zip_code
    end
  end
end
```

And in the model classes:

```rb
# person.rb

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  belongs_to :location
end
```

```rb
# building.rb

class Building < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  belongs_to :location
end
```

```rb
# location.rb

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  # With a little work, a polymorphic `has_one` could be added here.

  def calc_latitude
    # ...
  end

  def calc_longitude
    # ...
  end
end
```

Then, of course, I could do things like this: `@building.location.calc_longitude`.

However, this seems a little overkill. Wouldn't I then have to query the database every time I wanted to access the location of a `Person` or `Building`, even if I've already loaded them? What's the best solution?

Comment: What you're calling "overkill" is a canonical solution, but not the only solution. Whether or not it's best for *you* is subject to a lot of other context and opinion. Note you can do various joins so data is retrieved in a single database call.

Comment: @DaveNewton I see. Are there any other viable solutions that don't involve a separate database table? It seems (to me) like I shouldn't need to separate the data into multiple tables since I'm only using instances of the location data once. If not, though, could you point me to a resource describing how to do the joins you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: The Rails docs cover all of this as do many tutorials.

Comment: If you're worried about performance from all these joins and tables you can look into materialized views, Mysql and Postgres have good support for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not overkill. Rails allows you to use [`eager_load`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load) or [`preload`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/preload), depending on each case. If you are worried about database performance, you can use these methods to limit the number of database queries.

However, your locations may look the same during the first development cycle, but they can become more complex and have different behaviours, so you can then refactor them with [STI](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html):

```rb
class Location < ActiveRecord; end
class BuildingLocation < Location; end
class PersonLocation < Location; end
```

Having repeated data separated in different tables is a good approach.
If your locations per user and per building share the same records, you can take a look into a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) relationship. Example:

```rb
class Location < ActiveRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :persons
  has_and_belongs_to_many :buildings
end

# then you can have the same location for both users and buildings
Person.first.location # => <#Location id: 1, ..>
Building.first.location # => <#Location id: 1, ..>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! I had completely forgotten about the ability to use `eager_load`, `preload`, `includes`, etc. This should work well. Unless a better answer is posted soon, I'll likely accept yours.

Comment: yeah, I'm also wondering what other options, but this one considered to be rails-way